# Is [admin / admin] acceptable for all local websites?

Tags: security

Are there security issues with using the same credentials [admin / admin] for all client websites on a working, local server ?

Comment: Are the login forms for these sites accessible via the internet?

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: No issues then. It's a local sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

As @montrealist says, using an insecure username and password combination on a local webserver installation **that is not publicly accessible** is not necessarily a security concern.

If the server is publicly accessible, a secure username and password should be used of course.